# Cannot get check value from DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. Cannot cast cell value to bool C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in a DataGridView where users can check to verify an item. To check if an item has already been verified, I use this:

```
private void paymentsTbl_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = paymentsTbl.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        bool chk = (bool)row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value;
        if (chk == true)
        {
            row.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
```

This triggers when a row is added and makes the row read only if something had already been verified. This works. So now, the user clicks a button, and then I want to go through the datagridview to see what all the user checked.

```
private void verifyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   bool chk;
   foreach(DataGridViewRow row in paymentsTbl.Rows)
   {
       if(row.ReadOnly == false)
       {                                
             chk = (bool)row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value;
             if (chk)
             {
                   //Do Something
             }
       }
   }
}
```

This does not work. It gives me an error: Specified cast is not valid. on the line:

> chk = (bool)row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value;

I've been researching what I'm doing wrong but I've just been following examples online and getting the same result. Can someone please tell me how the first code could work perfectly but not the second?

EDIT: Here is how the rows are added to the DGV, where it says "verify" and "penalty" are both check box columns:

```
using (SqlDataReader Read = Com.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (Read.Read())
    {
        if (Read["VerificationStatus"].ToString() == "VERIFIED")
        {
            verify = true;

        }
        else
        {
            verify = false;
        }

        if (Read["Penalty"].ToString() == "Y")
        {
            penalty = true;
        }
        else
        {
            penalty = false;
        }

        paymentsTbl.Rows.Add(Read["PaymentID"].ToString(), Read["PrimaryHolder"].ToString(), Read["CertificateNum"].ToString(), Read["IntStartDate"].ToString(), Read["IntEndDate"].ToString(),
            Read["PaymentAmount"].ToString(), Read["RoundedInterest"].ToString(), verify, penalty, Read["PenaltyAmt"].ToString(), Read["TotalPaid"].ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: You may be able to cast the __Cell__ to DataGridViewCheckBoxCell but hardly its __Value__ - You should also add a pair of parenthesis on the last line of code: `chk = (bool)(row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value);`

Comment: You're right however, when just casting the value to bool it gives me a 'Specified cast is not valid' error. I changed my original post to reflect this.

Comment: The cast always refers to the __very next__ entity, here it should be the Value but in your code it is `row`. Change to `chk = (bool)(row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value);`

Comment: Added the paranthesis and got the same error. I just don't understand.

Comment: Is the value `==DbNull.Value`?

Comment: @Charlieface the value is checked by the user. So it is null from the database, I tried checking using == DbNull.Value but it gives me an error on DbNull that it doesn't recognize that.

Comment: The Value is in the DGV and should be tested against `null`, not `DbNull`..

Comment: The datagrid was filled from a database but it shouldn't read null at all. I either want a check or unchecked value as it is a checkbox

Comment: If you haven't set any value before, the Column / Cell value is either `null` or `DbNull.Value`. Maybe initialize all Fields to `false` beforehand, if you haven't. Also, if you're using a DataTable, remember to set `[DataTable].AcceptChanges();` right after you have loaded it.

Comment: Just to confirm, your grid has `AllowUserToAddRows` set to false?

Comment: Where is the first snippet of code called? You comment that… _”This triggers when a row is added and makes the row read only if something had already been verified. This works.”_  …? This may well work DEPENDING on WHERE/WHEN it is called. However, It will NOT work if the code is in the grids `RowsAdded` event. Again, WHERE is the first snippet of code run? In addition, what do you mean by… _”makes the row read only if something had already been verified”_ ? this does not make sense or is very broad in scope… what is this “something” that has already been verified?

Comment: Lastly, I am unable to get the invalid cast error as you describe in the second code snippet, I can get a `null` exception if… `row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value` … is `null`, however, if the value is not `null` the cast always succeeds. You need to give a better example of what you are trying to accomplish and clearly state where each code snippet is getting executed. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: @Jimi No DataTable. This is how I set that particular column based on input from the database:  if (Read["VerificationStatus"].ToString() == "VERIFIED") {  verify = true;  }
                                else
                                {
                                    verify = false;
                                }

Comment: @LarsTech correct, users cannot add rows only edit

Comment: @JohnG the first snippet of code in my post is in the RowsAdded Event, that works. The second snippet of code is in a Button Click event, this does not work. I'm using the same method to cast both values.

Comment: In the snippet you posted, there's no relation with a DataGridView. Show what is the DataSource of your DataGridView, how the Control's Columns are built, the exact content of the `VerificationStatus` Column (the DGV's), its data Type and how its values got there.

Comment: @JohnG i included the events that enclosed my code snippets in an edit. Casting the value to bool is where the error is thrown. I added this if to check if the value is null: if(row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value == null)
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("IT IS NULL");
                                } but the program does not enter this if.

Comment: The code in the grids `RowsAdded` event will ONLY work if you are NOT using a data source for the grid. After I changed this, (as I was using a `DataSource` for the grid) and ran the code it does work. However, again I am unable to get the cast error in the button click code as you describe. Can you show the column definitions of the grid?

Comment: @Jimi Check edit in post.

Comment: @JohnG Right I'm not using a data source. Check edit in post to see how the datagrid is originally filled. Thereafter the user can check the checkboxes and that is where my problem starts, I want to see which check boxes the user checks using a button click event.

Comment: I understand WHAT you are trying to do, however your posted code does not reproduce what you describe. I am not getting the cast error as you describe. Again show the column definitions you have created in the grid. Specifically the "VerificationStatus" column. I am lost as to why you do not use a `DataSource` for the grid. There is no reason not to, it will make your job MUCH easier.

Comment: @JohnG that is so strange I am equally at a loss, let me put a screenshot so you can see maybe you'll see something I'm not.

Comment: @JohnG I put screenshots, and what do you mean by column definitions? The Verification Status column is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Comment: Something else i discovered after putting the breakpoint: the row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value is in fact giving a true value but it just throws an error for the cast... Maybe I need to restart or...? Ha this is something strange...

Comment: I suggest a reboot. AND I am not trying to tell you how to do what you want; however, I cannot stress how much easier this would be if you used a `DataSource` for the grid. Like your last question where we went back and forth and you finally came up with what I considered an awkward solution. In this case, and similar to the previous case, to make this less complicated and less error prone, read ALL the data into a `DataTable.` The Boolean columns will automatically translate into check box columns in the gird. So you do not have to add the columns manually.

Comment: Then after the `DataTable` is set as a `DataSource` to the grid, you could loop through the rows and set the proper rows to read only. When you try to do this as your current code does by MANUALLY adding the rows, does two things, 1) creates MUCH MORE work for you 2) opens up the code to more errors as you are a witness of here. Can you give a valid reason WHY you do not use a `DataSource` for the grid considering you could from the posted query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I don't know why this error is happening but I realize that the Value is still giving a "true" value, so instead of bool, I change it to row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value.ToString(); and made the if (chk == "true") and that worked. Go figure.

Comment: I mean no disrespect and am only trying to help. First, I am glad you found another “workaround” solution. However, I would like to point out that comments like _”I don’t know why this error is happening”_ and succumbing to NEVER understanding the error and why it is happening, and simply adding some additional “workaround” code, is going to come back and bite you in the future. Particularly when learning, it is VERY important to know “why” errors happen and “how” to properly fix them. Otherwise, one of these days, NO “workaround” is going to fix the error. Just a heads up and Good Luck.

Comment: I get you and fully agree. The solution you gave would have worked too I bet but I just decided this workaround would be easier than backtracking through what I have already. But also that wouldn't have told me why this error is happening either, like I said I casted the same object in another line with no error so my rational is this is just a problem with my IDE. Thanks for your help though I'll need it again for sure!

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring `chk` as `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` and then trying to assign a `bool` type to it. You just need to get the value into a bool and check that:

```cs
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in paymentsTbl.Rows)
{
       if(row.ReadOnly == false)
       {                                
             bool chk = (bool)row.Cells["VerificationStatus"].Value;
             if (chk)
             {
                   //Do Something
             }
       }
}
```

Comment: I had that at first, changed my original post to show what I originally had, when casting the cell value to bool it gives me a 'Specified cast is not valid' error on that line